# linux/list.h - How to safely remove items from the list?

Tags: c, list, linux-kernel

In the comments of [`linux/list.h`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.7.6/include/linux/list.h) it is written that:

1. On using `list_del_entry`:  *Note: `list_empty` on entry does not return true after this, the entry is in an undefined state.*
2. For `list_del`: *This is only for internal list manipulation where we know the prev/next entries already!*

So, how would I safely remove an object from linked list and make sure that `list_empty` is functional or make sure that next linked list node deletion is correct?

This is my implementation currently:

```
struct kool_list{
    int to;
    struct list_head list;
    int from;
};

struct kool_list *tmp;
struct list_head *pos, *q;
struct kool_list mylist;

list_for_each_safe(pos, q, &mylist.list){
         tmp= list_entry(pos, struct kool_list, list);
         printf("freeing item to= %d from= %d\n", tmp->to, tmp->from);
         list_del(pos);
         free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: You need to use a lock if the list can be used from two contexts. The notation `_safe()` appears to be safe only for list traversal (reading) in the forward direction.  Some `archs` can be written lock-free, but Linux has yet to do this. (This may have been known, but I think it is worth mentioning).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the comments. The first one says that `list_empty(&entry->list)` will not return true. However, if you remove all elements from the list (the way you do it is correct) and do `list_empty(&mylist.list)` you will get true as a result.

If for some reason you want to keep the entry's `struct list_head` in an internally consistent state, use `list_del_init`.

Secondly, `__list_del` is for internal usage only, `list_del` is fair game.

Comment: +1, I'd also like to note that `list_del()` isn't for internal usage, `__list_del()` is.

Comment: +1 See also http://lwn.net/Articles/336255/ which gives some overview on use patterns.