# I'm doing womething wrong when iterating the kernel linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Thanks to [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33933346/11108302) I have mostly got how the Linux kernel linked lists work. However, the code examples in the answer are not 100% clear, and based on those alone I have written some code that gives me some issues when iterating the list.

In my module, I've initialized the list as a

```
struct list_head list_of_somethings;
```

in my `__init` function, I initialize it like this (I don't really get how the `LIST_HEAD` macro has to be used):

```
list_of_somethings.next = &list_of_somethings;
list_of_somethings.prev = &list_of_somethings;
```

This is how I add an element to the list:

```
            struct something *new_entry = kzalloc(sizeof(struct something), GFP_KERNEL);
            new_entry->some_datum=1;
            // other new_entry params are set
            // [...]
            list_add(&(new_entry->list), &list_of_somethings);
```

Where `struct something` is defined as:

```
struct something {
    struct list_head list;
    uint8_t some_datum;
    // other data
    // ...
};
```

This is how I iterate all elements in the linked list to find the one I need:

```
        struct list_head *pos;
        struct list_head *head = &list_of_somethings;
        
        struct something *seeked = NULL;

        list_for_each(pos, head) {
            struct something *pos_entry = container_of(pos, struct something, list);
            if (pos_entry->some_datum == 1) {
                seeked = pos_entry;
                break;
            }
        }
```

And this is how I free the whole list on `__exit`:

```
struct list_head *pos;
struct list_head *head = &list_of_somethings;

list_for_each(pos, head) {
    struct something *pos_entry = container_of(pos, struct something, list);
    // free eventual dynamically allocated structures which are fields of pos_entry
    kfree(pos_entry);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I get general protection faults when I try to delete the whole list, and I don't get what I expect when retrieving an element from the list. Could you please help me understand how these should be done?

Comment: It is not allowed to remove the element during iteration with `list_for_each`, you need to use `_safe` version. See also that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332381/linux-list-h-how-to-safely-remove-items-from-the-list.

Comment: I see. But in general is my understanding of the lists correct? Like, will the original element never have an "entry" associated to it and only serve as the "head" (and that's why the `list_for_each` statements start from `(head)->next` https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/list.h#L538)?

Comment: "will the original element never have an "entry" associated to it and only serve as the "head"" - `list_of_somethings` is actually a **head** of the list. The head doesn't correspond to any list element.

Comment: You may also look at simplified example of use this technique in user space https://pastebin.com/TwN3SiCd.